# Node + Express, JWT auth problem - I don't understand it clearly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, mern

I'm working on my first MERN stack project, and I don't understand JWT, I've watched many tuts and I get the concept, but when it comes to realization I just can't do it. :/

So, I have a couple of routes here. I made controllers for them
The last one (user) is supposed to be protected

```
const router = express.Router();

const authController = require("../controllers/auth.controller");
const auth = require("../middleware/authorization");

router.post("/register", authController.register);
router.post("/login", authController.login);
router.get("/user", auth(), (req, res) => {
  res.json({ status: "ok" });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Now, the login controller looks like that

```
exports.login = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    if (!email || !password) {
      return res.json({ Error: "All fields are required" });
    }

    User.findOne({ email }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) return err;

      if (!user) return res.json({ Error: "This user doesnt exists" });

      user.comparePassword(password, function (err, isMatch) {
        if (err) return err;
        if (isMatch === false) return err;
      });

      const payload = { _id: user._id };
      const token = jwt.sign(payload, jwt_secret);

      res.cookie("token", token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        expire: new Date() + 3000,
      });

      return res.json({ status: "ok", token: token, id: payload });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};
```

I save token for the cookie. Now I want to check if the user is authorized to enter the protected route with authorization middleware.

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const passport = require("passport");

const User = require("../models/user.model");

const authorize = (req, res, next) =>
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false });

module.exports = authorize;
```

How do I do that? And then what? I'm completely lost at this point. Is my code even good and secure?

```
const { jwt_secret } = require("./variables");
const User = require("../models/user.model");
const passportJwt = require("passport-jwt");

const ExtractJwt = passportJwt.ExtractJwt;
const JwtStrategy = passportJwt.Strategy;

const jwtOptions = {
  secretOrKey: jwt_secret,
  jwtFromSecret: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
};

const jwtStrategy = new JwtStrategy(jwtOptions, (payload, done) => {
  User.findById(payload.sub, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return done(err, null);
    }
    if (user) {
      return done(null, user);
    } else {
      return done(null, false);
    }
  });
});

exports.jwt = jwtStrategy;
```

Also, I've implemented JWT strategy and I don't understand at what "point" am I supposed to use it.

If someone will be able to help me - I would be really thankful, as I'm pretty much stuck. Much love for y'all.

Comment: do you want authentication with passport?? or without passport??

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi with passport

Comment: check this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ne0tLHm1juE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passport is created to be able to use different authentication / authorization mechanisms in an easy way, you can use many strategies such as JWT or OAuth2 etc... but all strategies do the same thing which is given a set of credentials, retrieve the user or fail.

In your case you have implemented the JWT Strategy, but I'm not sure if you registered it for passport to be able to use it

http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/

```js
passport.use(jwtStrategy)
```

After that, to be able to authenticate request, you can simple add passport middleware to your route handler

http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/

```js
router.get('/user', passport.authenticate('jwt'), (req, res) => {
  /** The authenticated user **/
  return res.json(req.user)
})
```